# function select2() lost after forward from servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using [Bootstrap2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html) and [Select2 3.4.2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) in jsp file. I want to override the Bootstrap select style by Select2 library. It works when jsp file is loaded in the first time, but after submitting the selection to servlet and forward back to the same jsp from servlet, I found the function select2() of select object has lost, and the select box change to Bootstrap style. It looks like select2.js has no effect, Why is that? Please help.

Following is my code snippet

selectCategory.jsp:

```
            <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <% 
            //Cannot include bootstrap.css twice
            Boolean hasBootstrap = (Boolean)request.getAttribute("hasBootstrap");
            if (hasBootstrap == null) {
            %>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href=" <%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/bootstrap2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href=" <%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/bootstrap2.3.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        padding-top: 60px;
                        padding-bottom: 40px;
                    }
                </style>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/bootstrap2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
                <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/bootstrap2.3.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"> </script>
                <script src=" <%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/bootstrap2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
        <%
                hasBootstrap = true;
                request.setAttribute("hasBootstrap", hasBootstrap);
            } //end of if
        %>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.css" />
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.js"> </script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        //$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        var sel = $('.selectpicker');
        var sel2 = $('#selectCat');
        $('#selectCat').select2();
    });
    </script>

<body>
    ...


        <select class="selectpicker" id="selectCat" name="selectCat" onchange="getSubject()">
```

servlet:

```
String url = "/standard/selectCategory.jsp";
RequestDispatcher successView = req.getRequestDispatcher(url);
successView.forward(req, res);
```

My problem is why the $('#selectCat').select2() lost when the request is forwarded from servlet?

---

### Update:

Look like the root cause is from include jQuery library twice

Because I include another jsp to render the query result, and this jsp need use tablesorter,
so I just include jQuery and tablesorter library here. I think the second included jQuery library has some effect on the select2 library which is included previously, so the select2() is lost. After remove the duplicate included library, the result is fine.

But I did an experiment, the result seems not what I expect

file1.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/tablesorter/style.css" />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.css" />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.js"> </script>

...

            <div class="secondary">
                <%if (request.getAttribute("listStandard") != null) {%>
                    <jsp:include page="file2.jsp"/>
                <%} %>
            </div>
```

file2.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/tablesorter/style.css" />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.css" />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/jquery/select2-3.4.2/select2.js"> </script>
```

I thought the second included select2.js in file2.jsp should take effect, but it doesn't

Comment: Are you getting any Java Script error?

Comment: I got the following error : TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
$('#selectCat').select2();

Comment: Check if JS is loading properly where select2() function is. You can check this in Firebug, Net tab. Also, try putting select2() call in document.ready function. This might help you https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2171

Comment: Thanks, Saurabh. I have found the root cause. With your post, it reminded me that I might include js twice. I review my files, it did that I included jQuery library twice after user submit the form, the later jQuery library seems override the previous select2 library.